# Can an extension on one chrome account interact with a different chrome account?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

One of my chrome accounts is part of an organization that automatically installs a chrome extension that allows them to see every tab you open, how long you are on it, your web history, and so on (it also lets them access and see what is currently on your screen). If this extension is only on one of the chrome accounts, and I have a different chrome account on the same computer, can that extension see my history and what I am doing on my private chrome account?

I've checked other websites and haven't really seen anything that answers my question exactly.